# DateTime parse exact error only on Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Hi guys I am having a problem with DateTime.ParseExact code. The error only shows in internet explorer and not on any other browser.

```
DateTime InsertTime = DateTime.ParseExact(CMS.Helpers.ValidationHelper.GetString(formRecord.GetValue("FormUpdated"),""), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Error is:

System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Example Value of "FormUpdated" = 2/1/2019 10:22:04 AM

Comment: You know what `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:s` can mean `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:s` depending on your current culture's date separator? Does the datetime always contain slashes? Then use `dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH:mm:s`

Comment: So what should i use to make it standerdised? I am writing this code for a company and people from around the world with different date times will be using this

Comment: Set the culture for your project.

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: [HOW TO: Set Current Culture Programmatically in an ASP.NET Application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306162/how-to-set-current-culture-programmatically-in-an-asp-net-application).

Comment: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

This is the issue i am receving now